# Add n seconds to time only (no date)

Tags: python, datetime, time

I am trying to add `n` seconds to the current time.

```
import datetime
seconds = 3
currenttime = datetime.datetime.now().time()
finaltime = currenttime + datetime.timedelta(0, seconds)
```

and

```
import datetime
import time
currenttime = time.time()
finaltime = currenttime + datetime.timedelta(0, seconds)
```

both produce `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)`.

```
currenttime = datetime.datetime.now()
finaltime = str(currenttime + datetime.timedelta(0, seconds))
```

works fine but it includes the date, which I don't need.

Is my syntax incorrect? Is there an easier way of achieving this?

Comment: Why not just time.time () + n?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot sum `time()` object and a `timedelta()`, because there is no defined way to handle the overflow. What would midnight + 1 second be?

Keep a date attached to the time, and add the `timedelta()` to that object. You can always extract the `time()` object later on, or format just the time component:

```
import datetime
seconds = 3
currenttime = datetime.datetime.now()
finaltime = currenttime + timedelta(seconds=seconds)
print finaltime.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: @JoranBeasley: that is locale dependent though.

Comment: yeah I guess ... so in some places you might end up with `"%h:%M:%S %p" `... not sure thats terrible

Comment: @MartijnPieters I forgot to mention that I am actually converting seconds to milliseconds and then adding to current time, which was why I didn't use `strftime`.

Comment: @Eric: I am only using `.strftime()` as an example to show that if your end product is a string, you don't need to extract the `datetime.time` object at all.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, extracting the time is exactly what I wanted to do, just with milliseconds as well. `finaltime.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f)` did the trick. Thank you for your help!